# Is it better to use state management or database trips in the case of 10 rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view of about 10 records. I want to allow the user to sort the rows by pressing up and down arrows on a row to move them up and down in desired order. I have a sort value column that will keep track in database.

I am not going to use any client side scripting, so each up and down arrow will cost me a post back.

The question is: As the user presses up or down to sort the row, would it be better to make a database trip for each sort request and resolve sorting at database Or manage the grid view data source in state and after all sorting is done, persist to database?

It seems the more concurrent users there are, individual database trips would be better right?

Comment: What does your benchmark say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how big the underlying dataset is and how efficient your session state provider is. It is impossible to answer in general.

Note, that using the session for this is hard because the user can have multiple pages open. Also, changes in data will not be visible to the user until he gets a new session.

The performance advantages would have to be quite big to make this worthwhile.

Strive to achieve a stateless application. Only deviate from this principle in important cases.